# represent different datasources for an Asp.net gridview binding? (design help)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, design-patterns

I am running into a bit of a design problem and always seem to run into some variety of the same issue.  While I realize there is a design issue, I cannot say what the problem is nor how I could go about correcting it.

An issue I am running into specifically is in the code to abstract the DAO access.  I like the idea of this because I could move to a Service-based data retrieval with minimal impact (I believe).  And more reports could be added and accessed through the existing method.

Also, with each of the reports containing their own set of columns, I don't know of a way to allow the GridView to load them (the code I posted doesn't run due to the empty Interface).

My goal is to be able to select a 'report' from a list, then populate a gridview based upon the report.

```
        public void LoadReportFor(string reportName)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = RetrieveReportDataFor(reportName, DateTime.Now);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private List<IReportRecord> RetrieveReportDataFor(string reportName, DateTime date)
    {
        List<IReportRecord> records;
        switch (reportName)
        {
            case "Timesheet":
                records = reportSDAO.GetTimeSheetReport(date);
                break;

            case "Salary":
                records = reportsDAO.GetSalaryReport(date);
                break;
            default:
                records = new List<IReportRecord>();
        }
        return records;
    }

    public class TimeSheetRecord : IReportRecord
    {
        public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }

        public int EmpID { get; set; }

        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        public double HoursWorked { get; set; }
    }

    public class SalaryRecord : IReportRecord
    {
        public int EmpID { get; set; }

        public double Salary { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IReportRecord
    {
    }
}
```

Updated.

I have decided to merge the LoadReportFor and RetrieveReportDataFor methods.  After giving my trouble some thought I didn't have a reason to have two methods.

Comment: Can you let the gridview autogenerate the columns?

Comment: Dave, I am actually doing that.  I get an error at runtime stating the gridview doesn't know how to process the columns.  I believe it's because the list I am using as the datasouce uses an empty interface. Once I add properties to IReportRecord the grid loads as expected.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also, unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: John, I don't understand the purpose of removing 'thanks in advance' as its a polite gesture to the community for their time. Frankly, claiming that SO doesn't use 'thanks', ect is a bit of a stretch as it's not mentioned in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

GridView has a Readonly property called Columns, which is a set of columns. It is readonly, but its elements are not readonly, you can add/modify/delete elements from it.

If you would like to buy a wheel instead of reinventing it, I can recommend Telerik.